# How to block loading kernel module only in single user boot when blacklist fails?

Tags: debian, boot, kernel-modules, sysvinit

On a "Linux debian 2.6.32-5-amd64 #1 SMP" installation where loading a kernel module (mpt2sas) is desired to be delayed to be loaded after starting sshd and users can remotely login, the mpt2sas module was disabled from loading in single user boot, by:

```
$ echo 'blacklist mpt2sas' >> /etc/modprobe.d/mpt2sas.conf; depmod -aeF /boot/System.map-2.6.32-5-amd64; update-initramfs -u -k $(uname -r)
```

Later on a `modeprobe -v mpt2sas` will be run in /etc/rc.local.

**After installing a newer mpt2sas driver**, using `dpkg -i mpt2sas-15.00.00.00-3_Debian6.0.5.amd64.deb` the result is that the old driver is renamed from `/lib/modules/2.6.32-5-amd64/kernel/drivers/scsi/mpt2sas/mpt2sas.ko` to `/lib/modules/2.6.32-5-amd64/kernel/drivers/scsi/mpt2sas/mpt2sas.ko.orig` and the new driver is installed at `/lib/modules/2.6.32-5-amd64/weak-updates/mpt2sas/mpt2sas.ko`.

The side effect is that the line **blacklist mpt2sas** in `/etc/modprobe.d/mpt2sas.conf` **no longer has any effect**, when modules are loaded in the single user boot process, mpt2sas is loaded as first kernel module.

Regression:

- I know that /etc/modprobe.d/mpt2sas.conf is still being loaded, because when entering a faulty line in this file, a warning is display at console during boot (4 times).
- Running `depmod -aeF /boot/System.map-2.6.32-5-amd64; update-initramfs -u -k -t $(uname -r); reboot` doesn't improve.
- Adding kernel boot parameter `modprobe.blacklist=mpt2sas` doesn't improve.

How can I block loading the new mpt2sas kernel module during the single user boot phase? (I still want to load mpt2sas using `modprobe` in /etc/rc.local).

Comment: I’m not sure what exactly init system do you use, but in OpenRC you can configure a service named ‘local’ through /etc/conf.d/local and define there functions `local_start` and `local_stop`, put your modprobe line in local_start then move `local` service to desired position, e.g. if your sshd is running at runlevel ‘boot’ place ‘local’ to default runlevel with your rc-script managing utility (rc-update, update-rc.d or something), or specify sshd in `need` dependencies for ‘local’ service in rc.conf (there are many examples).

Comment: Please add details about your OS. Debian/Ubuntu? Version? On SLES this would be solved by removing unwanted drivers from /etc/sysconfig/kernel followed by mkinitrd.

Comment: @Nils The OS was hidden in the driver name, mpt2sas-15.00.00.00-3_**Debian**6.0.5.amd64.deb. I will add OS and version more explicitly to the base question.

Comment: Is [this question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/59017/how-to-install-much-newer-mpt2sas-driver-version-in-debian-squeeze) of yours not about just the same?

Comment: @Nils That question is not about the same. That question is about installing a newer driver. This question is about blocking it from loading in single user boot mode, after having loaded that newer mpt2sas driver version.

Comment: @tijagi How can I find (on Debian 6.0.6) which init system exactly I do use?

Comment: @pro-backup, the simpliest way is to check your root shell whether it has rc-update or update-rc.d available. The first one is from openrc and the second comes with sysvinit.

Comment: @tijagi `# which update-rc.d` returns `/usr/sbin/update-rc.d` so the init system in use is sysvinit.

Comment: @pro-backup you’re definitely on a right way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check that your module is not listed in file `/etc/modules`. This file lists the modules that must be loaded at boot time according to http://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-faq/ch-kernel.en.html#s-modules

When the module name - mpt2sas in this case - is listed in file `/etc/modules`:

1. Remove that mpt2sas line or comment it by prepending a hash. Line "`mpt2sas`" becomes "`#mpt2sas`".
2. Update the initramfs image file: `depmod -aeF /boot/System.map-$(uname -r) && update-initramfs -u -k $(uname -r) -t`
3. And reboot

Comment: *facepalm* - this must have been too obvious to have overlooked! Anyway, you have edited the `/etc/modules` file yourself, probably.

Comment: @gertvdijk For a Linux novice nothing is obvious at all.

Answer (score 2):

Add this to your kernel boot command line (in e.g. Grub, press <kbd>e</kbd> and edit the kernel boot parameters):

```
modprobe.blacklist=mpt2sas
```

More on this on the [Arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Kernel_modules#Using_kernel_command_line_2).

Comment: This kernel parameter `modprobe.blacklist=mpt2sas` does not change the loading of the /weak-updates/mpt2sas.ko module during boot in our case.